# Changing CardView background colour through MvvmCross view model

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross, android-cardview

I'm trying to bind the background colour of my CardView to my view model, but I'm getting this error back from Mvx:

> MvxBind:Warning: 11.66 Failed to create target binding for binding
>   CardBackgroundColor

I'm not sure whether I'm using the wrong property binding in the AXML or in the view model.

Here is the property I'm trying to bind it to in the view model:

```
public int EventEntryBackgroundColour
{
    get
    {
        return IsRead
            ? Resource.Color.yellow
            : Resource.Color.White;
    }
}
```

I've also tried using it as a string type to return a colour in **HEX**, but it still doesn't work.

Here's the attribute, I'm setting on the CardView

```
cardview:MvxBind="CardBackgroundColor EventEntryBackgroundColour"
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. My solution...

**Converter:**

```
public class MessageStatusToColorDrawableConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, ColorDrawable>
    {
        protected override ColorDrawable Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            var context = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity>().Activity; // To get the context of the activity

            return value ? new ColorDrawable(new Color(ContextCompat.GetColor(context, Resource.Color.Pink))) : new ColorDrawable(new Color(ContextCompat.GetColor(context, Resource.Color.Green)));
        }
    }
```

**XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relay_archive"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        local:MvxBind="Background MessageStatusToColorDrawable(Status)">
```

We can't bind an `Android.Graphics.Color` property to `local:MvxBind="BackgroundColor...` since the `BackgroundColor` property wants you to use the `NativeColor` converter which uses an `MvxColor`.
However, the `local:MvxBind="Background...` property wants a drawable, hence my use of binding a `ColorDrawable`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked a very long time ago but maybe it will help somebody out.

The answer now is that you need to use **CardViewBackgroundColor** instead of **CardBackgroundColor**.

So in your case that would be:

```
cardview:MvxBind="CardViewBackgroundColor EventEntryBackgroundColour"
```

You should bind it to a Android.Graphics.Color though and **not** an integer. 
To do that, you can create a converter class like below:

```
public class BackgroundColorConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, Color>
{
    protected override Color Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value ? Color.Black : Color.White;
    }
}
```

You can call this converter from the xaml too and pass a boolean from your ViewModel to display the correct color. Example:

```
cardview:MvxBind="CardViewBackgroundColor BackgroundColor(Selected)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into the Value converters of MvvmCross: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters#the-mvx-color-valueconverters

Using those you can set a color like this:

```
local:MvxBind="BackgroundColor NativeColor(CurrentColor)"
```

Or for iOS:

```
set.Bind(field)
   .For(field => field.BackgroundColor)
   .To(vm => vm.CurrentColor)
   .WithConversion("NativeColor");
```

And Windows:

```
Fill="{Binding CurrentColor, Converter={StaticResource NativeColor}}"
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn, but, unfortunately this didn't work. I'm getting this error exception: _android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RoundRectDrawableWithShadow._ I've tested it on the text colour of a TextView and that works fine. Do you know of any examples of this with a CardView?

Answer (score 0):

I just defined a subclass of my cardview with a own property for it, since you cant directly access it else it seems and i didnt find a binding for it yet?

```
public class BindableColorCardView: CardView
{
    private Color m_cCardViewColor;
        public Color CardViewColor
    {
        get { return m_cCardViewColor; }
        set
        {
            m_cCardViewColor = value;
            SetCardBackgroundColor(m_cCardViewColor);
        }
    }
```

And then just used binded property with a ValueConverter.